# How to force close button to terminate all childforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have program that opens subwindows inside of it (mdi.parent). I have made component that is in one window under it, however, i want that that window never actually disposed after its created because i want to keep only one instance of it.

This can be made with code:

```
    // This prevents this window disposing from window close button, we want always show one and only
    // one instance of this window.
    FormClosing += (o, e) =>
                            {
                                Hide();
                                e.Cancel = true;
                            };
```

However, after this there is problem, closing program requires pressing close button press twice. First press closes subwindow and second terminates program. How this can be get around?

I am working with Winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Application.Exit()` in the form close event.

[Application.Exit - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit.aspx)

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes
>   all application windows after the messages have been processed.

Answer (score 2):

As Habib said, you can call `Application.Exit`, but:

> The Form.Closed and Form.Closing events are not raised when the
>   Application.Exit method is called to exit your application

If this is important to you, you can do something like this (MDI parent code):

```
    private Boolean terminating;

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!terminating)
        {
            terminating = true;
            Close();
        }

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Comment: In current solution this doesn't matter, but have to remember this if it will be an issue in some point later.

Comment: +1 This is a better way to solve the problem. `Application.Exit` is a hacky solution at best. Even if the hack is acceptable for now, there's no real drawback to doing it the right way the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside of your `FormClosing` event handler method is a bit too terse. It does its job of preventing the user from closing the form, but as you've also noticed, it prevents *you* from closing the form programmatically as well.

This is easily solved by testing the value of the [`CloseReason` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) of the [`FormClosingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) that are passed in each time the event is raised.

These will tell you the reason why the form is attempting to close. If the value is `CloseReason.UserClosing`, then you want to set `e.Cancel` to `true` and hide the form. If the value is something else, then you want to allow the form to continue closing.

```
// This prevents this window disposing when its close button is clicked by the
// user; we want always show one and only one instance of this window.
// But we still want to be able to close the form programmatically.
FormClosing += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            Hide();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
       Form[] ch = this.MdiChildren;
       foreach (Form chfrm in ch)
       chfrm.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Application.Exit if there is no processing happening when the application is closed. Otherwise, you can check `Application.OpenForms` collection in MDI parent's closing event and close all the other forms that are open.